# When to use square brackets and curly brackets in sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This might be a dumb question but here goes.

I've been following [this tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/) on sencha touch 2 app. I'm very new to Ext JS and I can't understand when to use `square brackets : [  .. ]` or `curly brackets : { .. }`.

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "top",
            title: "My Notes",
            items: [{
                xtype: "spacer"
            }, {
                xtype: "button",
                text: "New",
                ui: "action",
                id:"new-note-btn"
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

And like here

```
html: [
                        '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
                        "to use tabs, lists and forms to create a simple app</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch 2</h2>'
                    ].join("")
```

1. Can anyone help me with the proper use of curly and square bracket while coding for sencha touch?
2. Why not just go ahead with curly brackets { .. } ? Why does ext js have to use [ .. ] along with { .. }?

Comment: It might be interesting for you to take a basic javascript course. Because those things are pretty basic and essential. http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

Comment: well i did the w3schools basic course...didn't encounter the braces like this..anyways, thanks for the link, I'll go through it. Is ther any other "basic" topic I should cover before plunging into sencha touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just basic javascript.

The `[]` means an array, the `{}` means an object literal, so:

```
[{
    xtype: 'foo'
}, {
    xtype: 'bar'
}]
```

Is an array of object literals.